# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.example.kdotz.sunshine.app/location

Tags: java, android, illegalargumentexception

I am getting the below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.example.kdotz.sunshine.app/location
```

My URL is correct in WeatherContract:

```
public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.example.kdotz.sunshine.app";
```

My Manifest provider is below:

```
< provider
    android:authorities="com.example.kdotz.sunshine.app"
    android:name=".data.WeatherProvider" ></provider >
```

Are there any other locations my path could be off?

Link to my contentprovider is below: https://github.com/kdotzenrod517/Sunshine/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/kdotz/sunshine/app/data/WeatherProvider.java

Thanks,
Krista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the provider inside `<application> .... </application>` and make sure that it is not in `<activity> .... </activity>`.

```
<application>
 < provider
    android:authorities="com.example.kdotz.sunshine.app"
    android:name=".data.WeatherProvider" >
 </provider >
</application>
```